# NullReferenceException when trying to get version from assemblyinfo in UWP app

Tags: windows-10, uwp, nullreferenceexception, assemblyinfo

I get NullReferenceException when trying to get version from assemblyinfo in UWP app. Below is the code that I am using :

```
    return typeof(AssemblyInfo).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get version without using reflection, with code like:

```
   PackageVersion pv= Package.Current.Id.Version;
   string version= $"{pv.Major}.{pv.Minor}.{pv.Build}.{pv.Revision}";
```

Comment: Thanks Alexej...that was quick and resolved my problem :)